# CSS onmouseover gallery with php loop

Tags: php, css, image, gallery

I once created an image gallery using CSS which did the following:

1. Created a thumbnail gallery
2. Created a div where in there was placed 1x1 pixel images
3. on mouseover of thumbnails, these 1x1 pixel images expanded to fit the div size, with height being relative to length.
4. My code so far:

php:

```
echo '<div id="thumbnails">';
$files = glob("11-09-2012/*.*");
for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
{       //creating thumbnails
   $num = $files[$i];
   echo '<img src="'.$num.'" height="50px" id="thumb'.$files[$i].'"></img>';
};


   echo '</div><div id="gallery">';
   for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
{       //creating 1x1
   $num = $files[$i];
   echo '<img STYLE="position:absolute" src="'.$num.'" height="1px" width="1px" id="img'.$files[$i].'"></img>';
};
echo '</div>';
```

CSS:

```
#gallery {
margin: 0 auto; 
border-style: solid;
border-width: 3px;
border-color: #fff;
width: 800px;  
height: 600px;  
}
```

Now I'm not sure where to go - Any help is appreciated - alternative ways to do this, is as well.

Best regards - Jesper

Comment: I don't see any attempt to actually implement the mouseover. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: Well I wanted to create a CSS style like
    .thumb[$i]:hover{
     img[$i]:height 500px;
    }

Which of course doesn't work since my CSS file can't recognize the php.

Comment: Unfortunately you'll have to wait until CSS4 for a pure CSS solution to this problem. In the meantime, just some basic JavaScript will do.

Comment: "with height being relative to length."? height = length

Comment: length=width, oops.
Height relative to length, meaning that width of the image is scaled down percent wise compared to what height you set it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/yDUMT/

The jsfiddle shows the onMouseOver being used with a javascript function to enlarge the 1px when the thumbnail is mouse overed, and the onMouseOut being used with a javascript function to shrink the enlarged 1px image back down when the mouse is moved off the thumbnail.

Answer (score 2):

A naïve programmer might recommend jQuery, or attach an event to each individual image. Here's how the big boys do it:

```
(function() {
  var box = document.getElementById('thumbnails'),
      handler = function(e) {
        e = e||window.event;
        var tar = e.target || e.srcElement,
            type = e.type, id = tar.id, m, img;
        if( (m=id.match(/^thumb(.*)$/)) && (img=document.getElementById('img'+m[1]))) {
          img.style.height = img.style.width = type == "mouseover" ? "auto" : "1px";
        }
      };
  if( typeof box.attachEvent != "undefined") {
    box.attachEvent('onmouseover',handler);
    box.attachEvent('onmouseout',handler);
  }
  else {
    box.addEventListener('mouseover',handler);
    box.addEventListener('mouseout',handler);
  }
})();
```

The only change you need to make to your HTML is to remove the `width="1px" height="1px"` from your images and instead add `width:1px;height:1px;max-width:800px;max-height:600px;` to the image's style. This would be better done in the CSS file:

```
#gallery>img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 0;
    width: 1px; height: 1px;
    max-width: 800px;
    max-height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: I've added "$(document).ready" - yes/no? 

I've tried to correct parenthesis

I've tried adding the script to jquery.js file and calling this script: <head><script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>...</head>

Nothing seems to work :/

Comment: When an else alert("error"); is added, it gives this alert multiple times, and seems to crash my browser for some time x]
- So the if(...) doesn't work, @Kolink, would you take a look at it again?

Comment: Try `alert(id)` first, then `alert(id.match(/^thumb(.*)$/))`, then `alert(img)`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I appear to have missed some `)` and apparently my "clever" trick to use `attachEvent/addEventListener` doesn't work. I have corrected the errors. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yDUMT/2/)